# STS template Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a strange problem. When I want to create a new Spring MVC project in Springsource tools suite (New -> Spring Template Project -> Spring MVC Project), I get this:

[image: STS]
<sub>(source: [fii.cz](http://fii.cz/uypvmp))</sub>

I can't create some project even when I not specify the top-level package. Next or Finish buttons are still disabled.

Any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least one package level more (e.g. `cz.toby.test`). See the last `+` in the regex: Two groups are mandatory, `\w+`, followed by at least one more group.